# looking for hypergraph decompositions

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

there are many thms for/types of graph decompositions. in contrast,

> am looking for various types of [hypergraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) decompositions...?

also esp interested in graph analogs that translate somehow eg say is there a hypergraph analog of [modular graph decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_decomposition)? or also maybe [series-parallel graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_parallel_graph) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Tree decomposition in hyper graph is just natural extension of tree decomposition in normal graphs. e.g take a look at [this](http://www.labri.fr/perso/mazoit/uploads/Surface_duality_journal.pdf). But problems on hyper graphs are much harder. For example natural extension of list coloring in hyper graph is almost as hard as clique coloring in normal graphs (I think $\Pi^2_P$, it's a paper by Daniel Marx). In my opinion when coloring (which is highly connected to topological properties of a graph), is that hard, we cannot expect a good topological parameters.